# Using pyo3 and maturin for Python bindings. How to structure it?

Tags: python, rust, lifetime, pyo3, maturin

For an existing library, what is the best (or at least good) way to structure the project when creating Python bindings via `pyo3` / `maturin` ?

So far I figure I can either just annotate all the structs and impls with `#[pyclass]` and `#[pymethods]` directly in the original library along with a `#[pymodule] fn`, but this changes the return types and litters the original code with the additional attribute annotations.

The other option I can see is to basically copy + paste the library into a new lib with the appropriate `Cargo.toml` and `pyproject.toml`, and annotate all the desired structs/impls etc there instead. The benefit of this is you retain the original library as it was, but the downside is that for every implementation in the original, it requires doing the same thing in the secondary `pyo3` project which is a tedious task.

The crates `polars` and `tokenizers` both seem to do the latter, which I would prefer since I want to keep the original library without the additional attributes everywhere.

Is there a smart way to accomplish this, such as automate it ?

Comment: You don't need to copy the library, you just need to create wrapper structs and methods.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, do you mind giving an example ?

Comment: `polars` is an example. It doesn't copy behavior, only wraps the types.

Comment: I see, I need to have a better look at their method it seems. Nevertheless, does that not essentially mean doing the latter method I described? i.e. re-implementing the whole library, just adding the attributes above each object (wrapper structs, etc) ?

Comment: No, that's the point: you only need to reimplement the **interface**, not the **behavior**.

Comment: Okay thank you very much for your help. 

This is the sort of thing you mean right?

`#[pyclass]
pub struct PySQLContext {
    pub context: SQLContext,
}`
Where SQLContext is imported from polars via:

`use polars::sql::SQLContext;`

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant. Wrap the types and the methods.

Comment: One last question, is there any benefit to keeping the pyo3 project separate from the original library (like polars and tokenizers) ? Why not just create an additional file in each module in the original library to contain the wrappers, etc ?

Comment: It may be more clean this way, and it avoids from building pyo3 when all you want is to use the Rust library.